# Plupload rotating uploaded photos incorrectly but only on Safari

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, safari

I am using Plupload as my file uploader in an ASP.NET MVC web application.

Testing this web application on a PC, using Chrome, the photos I upload maintain the rotation of the photo file as saved on the hard drive. But when I email the same photos and save them on a MAC, checking that the photo rotation is the same on the MAC, as it was on the PC, when uploading, using Safari, using Plupload, the files are rotated randomly and incorrectly.

This issue occurs on Safari 6 and 8.

I do not have a clue where to start debugging this issue and am looking for suggestions as to where to start debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by looking at the EXIF metadata in the jpeg files, this is how to read in C#, I rotate the image based on a couple orientations that might come from iPhone,iPod Touch and some Android devices:

```
  using (
            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(binaryImagedata))
            )
        {
            //image.Width = EndSheetWidth;

            PropertyItem[] properties = image.PropertyItems;

            int Orientation = 0;

            foreach (PropertyItem p in properties)
            {

                if (p.Id == 274)
                {

                    Orientation = (int) p.Value[0];

                    if (Orientation == 6)

                        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

                    if (Orientation == 8)

                        image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);

                    break;

                }

            }
//...more code
}//end using
```